# Multiple .kv files manipulating 2 .kv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, screen

hi everyone for those from my last question here, sorry i didnt complete my game due to this problem that caught me in the finals, SO HERES THE THING i have a menu with 2 "START" buttons "START1" and "START2" so what i want is whenever i press the "START1" it takes me to the designated .kv file and when i press "START2" it goes to designated .kv file heres a pic of what i want and a sample of what ive done so far[image]

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition


ScreenManagement:

    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    GameScreen1:
    GameScreen2:


  Button:

    size_hint: 0.2,0.1
    font_size: 20


  MainScreen:

    name: "Start"

    Button:

        on_release: app.root.current = "game1"
        text: "START"
        color: 1,0,0,1

GameScreen1:

    name: "game1"

    Button:

        pos_hint: {"right":1,"top":0.5}
        color: 1,0,0,1 
        on_release: app.root.current = "game2"
        text: "Next"
        background: 0,1,0,1

    Label: 

        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        text: "Python\n\n Ruby"
        font_size:40

    Button:

        text: "HOME"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Start"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0}


GameScreen2:

    name: "game2"

    Button:

        pos_hint: {"right":1,"top":0.5}
        color: 1,0,0,1 
        on_release: app.root.current = "game1"
        text: "Next"
        background: 0,1,0,1

    Label: 

        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        text: "Assembly\n\n Prolog"
        font_size:40

    Button:

        text: "HOME"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Start"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0}
```

thats the programmer.kv

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition


ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    GameScreen1:
    GameScreen2:


Button:

    size_hint: 0.2,0.1
    font_size: 20


MainScreen:

    name: "Start"

    Button:

        on_release: app.root.current = "game1"
        text: "START"
        color: 1,0,0,1

GameScreen1:

    name: "game1"

    Button:

        pos_hint: {"right":1,"top":0.5}
        color: 1,0,0,1 
        on_release: app.root.current = "game2"
        text: "Next"
        background: 0,1,0,1

    Label: 

        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        text: "HELLO"
        font_size:40

    Button:

        text: "HOME"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Start"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0}


GameScreen2:

    name: "game2"

    Button:

        pos_hint: {"right":1,"top":0.5}
        color: 1,0,0,1 
        on_release: app.root.current = "game1"
        text: "Next"
        background: 0,1,0,1

    Label: 

        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        text: "WORLD"
        font_size:40

    Button:

        text: "HOME"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Start"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0}
```

thats the social.kv

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.label import Label



class MainScreen(Screen):

    pass

class GameScreen1(Screen):

    pass

class GameScreen2(Screen):

    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):

    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("social.kv")
presentation = Buider.load_file("programmer.kv")

class Myapp(App):

    def builder(self):

        return presentation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Myapp().run()
```

i tried to make 2 builders but since the two has a "MENU" screen on overwrote the other i guess i can say it this way. so i want to have just 1 menu with 2 START buttons like the picture above that would make one start to activate the designated .kv file, can anyone please help, right now i have no clue on how to do this im still reaserching.

Comment: I edited your post to show your `kv` files better, but there are several problems. First, any `kv` file should have only one `root` widget (see [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#overview)). Second, you have two lines in your `py` file that start with `presentation =`. That means that the first `presentation` is overwritten by the second. Please have a look at your `kv` files to make sure accurately represent your actual files. A more reasonable approach might be to just have one `kv` file with a `Screen` for the programmers view and another for the social view.

Comment: thanks for editing the files looks better now. i want this app to have a kv file with a screen for the programmers and another for the social but the problem is how to make both kv files to work like in parallel since both kv files up there have MAINSCREEN one overwrites the other but i want to work as the pic above e even tried to create a kv file to have only the MAINSCREEN but i didnt know how to link the START buttons to its own kv file i dont know if thats even possible

Comment: Both of your `kv` files will fail on loading with a `Only one root object is allowed` error. Please see the `kv` language [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html). Your description of how you want to use multiple `kv` files sounds exactly as multiple `Screen` widgets would be used, and that can be done with one `kv` file. There is no documented way to switch an app from one 'kv' file to another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do what you asked. Using 2 `kv` files. This does what a `ScreenManager` would do for you.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

presentation1 = Builder.load_string('''
Button:
    text: 'This is presentation1'
    on_press: app.switchToRoot2()
''')

presentation2 = Builder.load_string('''
Button:
    text: 'This is presentation2'
    on_press: app.switchToRoot1()
''')

class MultiplKVApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.root_layout.add_widget(presentation1)
        return self.root_layout

    def switchToRoot2(self, *args):
        self.root_layout.clear_widgets()
        self.root_layout.add_widget(presentation2)

    def switchToRoot1(self, *args):
        self.root_layout.clear_widgets()
        self.root_layout.add_widget(presentation1)

MultiplKVApp().run()
```

Note that both your `kv` files have instances of `MainScreen`, `GameScreen1`, and `GameScreen2`. So kivy will create two independent instances of each of those widgets.

Comment: ok so let me see if i got this. the ?MultiplKVApp works like the the Main Menu Screen of my picture up there, i can use it to switch between the "social" and "programmer" side. so using your idea and code i can replace the BUILDER.LOAD.STRING with BUILDER.LOAD_FILE right it will get the same result as long i have the APP.SWITCHTOROOT on in both .kv file i create right?